# Clear textbox selection in IE11 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to clear any text selection that may be active on the page, including selected text in a textbox. This works in Firefox and Chrome:

```
document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

It also works in IE for text selected on the page, but not text selected in a textbox.

I was doing the following for IE, which worked for both types of selections, but it is no longer supported in IE11:

```
document.selection.empty();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Call removeAllRanges() to deselect any selected text on the page, then add a new empty selection to deselect any selected text in the textbox. This covers all bases in all three browsers:

```
document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
document.getSelection().addRange(document.createRange());
```

Comment: The second line is absolutely required for IE browsers. You were the only person (during my last two days surfing) who was taking this into account. Even for newest IE (edge as well) without this does not clear selection in every cases. All IE versions (8,9,10,11,edge) require this.